# Update component state when clicking button inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe

Is it possible to update state, based on the click of a button located inside an iframe?

I have a component which looks a little something like the below.

Within the iframe, there is a button for the user to click. I'd like to be able to set the state to true once the button is clicked. Is it possible to do that?

```js
import ReactIframeResizer from 'react-iframe-resizer-super';

const Component = () => {
  const [state, setState] = useState(false);
  
  return (
    <ReactIframeResizer
      src={url}
    />
  )
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That might be possible if the domain of the iframe is in the same domain as your website. Then you would be able to add an event listener.

Comment: @EmielZuurbier - it's not the same domain. Does this mean it's not possible?

Comment: I do believe that is the case. You'd be dealing with the same-origin policy where you can't access an iframe if the origin is not the same. However, if you are the author of the site in the iframe, then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy) might be something to look into.